# WAMP localhost not found on other devices on local network

Tags: localhost, wamp, wampserver

I can access localhost via my PC which it is installed on but attempting to access it from another device connected to the same network I get "Not Found, The requested URL / was not found on this server."

Localhost works perfectly fine on the PC, but I cannot access it at all from another device. I have ensured that my Firewall isn't blocking it, so it's not that.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: If you are trying to access it using http://localhost on another computer, you will never hit it. You need to use your computer's local IP address instead of 'localhost'

Comment: Sorry should have pointed out, yes I am using my computer's IP address and it is definitely the correct one.

Comment: Is WAMP "online" - click icon, choose 'Put Online'?

Answer (score 0):

Have you allowed the port WAMP is using (by default - 80) on your subnet? You need to figure out what firewall software is on it. It could be part of your antivirus software, or even the Microsoft one.